# Android Studio Encoding with german umlaut characters Eg. Ä, Ü and Ö

Tags: encoding, android-studio

German Umlaut characters (Ä, Ü and Ö) are not supported in strings. I am using Android Studio (version 1.2 Beta).

The german characters Ä, Ö, Ü are not shown properly.

In my Gradle file I have assigned the following encoding:

```
compileOptions.encoding = 'windows-1252'
```

and here is the screenshot which is illustrating the situation

[image]

Edit: I see incorrect characters instead of Ä, Ö, Ü in the Emulator:

[image]

Comment: Where are you getting them? What characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the `UTF-8` encoding, as far as I know it supports German signs.

Comment: I have done so. Now I get the error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8 for assigning the string "Übersicht" to a variable.

Comment: Did you set IDE and Project encoding both to UTF-8?

Comment: Yes, both are set to UTF-8 too. The compiler tells me the chars Ä, Ü, Ö are unmappable characters for encoding UTF-8 as string-values eg. "Übersicht".

Comment: Try closing and reopening the IDE